# DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea without TransparencyKey?

Tags: .net, winforms, transparency, dwm, aero-glass

When using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` function I need to choose `Form.TransparencyKey`, a color that a glass will be drawn on instead.

The problem is that i writing image-edit tool, and when `TransparencyKey` color appear inside the edited image, the user see glass instead.

How do i extend the glass into client area without losing some color?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you should be using the `Form.TransparencyKey` property with DWM functions. That property relates to layered windows, which has nothing to do with the Aero glass effect. I assume the fact that it might work is more a consequence of implementation detail (like all 3 RGB values of the color you've set as the `TransparencyKey` are the same), rather than by design.

GDI treats black as the transparency color, so you should just paint the particular regions of your form that you want to appear as glass with a black brush. Because you're limiting the black fill to only those areas, there's no reason this should interfere with the rest of your UI.

Of course, any black text (such as that drawn on controls) that appears in the area you're rendering as glass is going to look ugly. The solution is either to switch to GDI+-based rendering or to move your controls outside of the area to be rendered as glass. If you need finer control over the area of your form that should appear glassy than provided by `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` (which literally just extends the frame by a set amount), look into using [`DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969508.aspx) instead. See [my more complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420528/how-can-i-get-aero-glass-on-a-windows-form-without-borders/4420564#4420564) on how to use that function.

Comment: Thanks, But how do i draw an image that has black color without making it transparent?

Comment: @DxCK: Like I said, only black areas within the border you've specified to `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` will be glass. The rest of the black on your form won't be transparent because it's not rendered as glass. If you render the *entire form* as a glass sheet (by passing -1 to the function), all black will be rendered as glass, even the text in controls. There's not much you can do about that. I haven't seen a good answer to the many [questions that have been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258295/aero-how-to-draw-solid-opaque-colors-on-glass), and I don't see the point in trying.