# Windows aero glass form text problem

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, aero-glass

I use windows form with GlassForm(using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;). my problem when I change form to GlassForm my textbox texts doesnt

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information for us to help you, could you perhaps post a screenshot or some sample code?

Comment: I think the OP means this: http://selimozyalcin.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-c-glass-form.html though it is unclear from the question

Comment: http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/5341/aaaui.png
http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/7720/bbbbaz.png
I use your links problem is same. My text visible transparent!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's how it works. With the Aero Glass effect applied, anything drawn in the color black will be rendered as transparent. That includes text in a textbox control. This general theme has been the subject of [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258295/aero-how-to-draw-solid-opaque-colors-on-glass) here. When well-written, they gather lots of upvotes, but few answers.

There just aren't a lot of good solutions here. All of them that I've come across qualify as both "ugly" and "hackish". Owner-drawing is a reasonable approach when you're using something like a label control, but I wouldn't recommend trying to draw your own textbox—it's just too hard to get right. [Someone tried to do that here](http://glassui.codeplex.com/); like I said, the result is both ugly and hackish. I wasn't satisfied with it for my own use, but it may work for you, depending on how high your standards are.

The goal with owner-drawing, of course, is either to do all of the drawing using GDI+ (which natively supports transparency) instead of GDI (which all of the built-in controls use by default), or calling functions like [`DrawThemeTextEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773312.aspx), which is specifically designed for rendering text with a shadow that is [somewhat] readable over glass.

As well, the usual tricks like enabling compatible text rendering (which causes the built-in controls to draw using GDI+ routines, as they did in the early versions of .NET) don't work for a textbox.

Honestly, your best bet is to place the textbox over a region of your form that is *not* rendered as glass. Use the [`DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969508.aspx) to selectively enable the glass effect behind certain areas of your form, rather than the entire thing. I provide a complete, ready-to-use .NET implementation in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420528/how-can-i-get-aero-glass-on-a-windows-form-without-borders/4420564#4420564).

Answer (score 3):

Place a panel on the form set the dock style to fill, set the panel's BackColor to color X and then set the form's TransparencyKey to the same color X.

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample out: 
http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Glass-In-C-An-Alternative-Approach.aspx

I was not studying it any further but putting a TextBox or Button or other components over this Aero glass area worked - the rendered component didn't have the transparency problem. The labels aren't perfect but these can be easily drawn with GDI+
The direct link to the sample project is here: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/MothGlass.zip

It looks like he puts a panel behind the control and setting the TransparencyKey for the panel.

[image]